# npm 25 vulnerabilities (19 moderate, 6 high) not resolved with npm audit fix

Tags: windows, security, npm, appium, audit

I've been trying with this issue for three days, I am just trying to install appium with flutter driver, but I keep facing this problems
I can provide the full npm audit report

jpeg-js  <=0.4.3
Severity: high
Uncontrolled resource consumption in jpeg-js - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-w7q9-p3jq-fmhm
Infinite loop in jpeg-js - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-xvf7-4v9q-58w6
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/@jimp/jpeg/node_modules/jpeg-js
@jimp/jpeg  <=0.12.0 || 0.16.1 - 0.16.2-canary.1094.1345.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of jpeg-js
node_modules/@jimp/jpeg
@jimp/types  <=0.11.1-canary.891.908.0 || 0.16.2-canary.919.1052.0 - 0.16.2-canary.1094.1345.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of @jimp/jpeg
node_modules/@jimp/types
jimp  >=0.3.6-alpha.5
Depends on vulnerable versions of @jimp/custom
Depends on vulnerable versions of @jimp/plugins
Depends on vulnerable versions of @jimp/types
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/jimp
node_modules/jimp
@appium/support  2.54.2 - 4.1.1
Depends on vulnerable versions of jimp
Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/@appium/support
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/@appium/docutils/node_modules/@appium/support
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/@appium/support
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-idb/node_modules/@appium/support
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-ios-device/node_modules/@appium/support
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-ios-simulator/node_modules/@appium/support
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-remote-debugger/node_modules/@appium/support
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/node_modules/@appium/support
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-xcode/node_modules/@appium/support
@appium/base-driver  8.0.2 - 9.3.7
Depends on vulnerable versions of @appium/support
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-driver
@appium/base-plugin  1.8.0 - 2.2.7
Depends on vulnerable versions of @appium/support
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/@appium/base-plugin

semver  <5.7.2 || >=7.0.0 <7.5.2
Severity: moderate
semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw
semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/normalize-package-data/node_modules/semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/utf7/node_modules/semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/@appium/docutils/node_modules/semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/@appium/support/node_modules/semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-idb/node_modules/semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-ios-device/node_modules/semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-ios-simulator/node_modules/semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-remote-debugger/node_modules/semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/node_modules/semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-xcode/node_modules/semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium/node_modules/semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/read-pkg/node_modules/semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/utf7/node_modules/semver
node_modules/utf7/node_modules/semver
@appium/docutils  0.2.0 - 0.4.3
Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/@appium/docutils
appium
Depends on vulnerable versions of @appium/docutils
Depends on vulnerable versions of @appium/support
Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
Depends on vulnerable versions of yaml
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium
appium-xcuitest-driver  4.21.8 - 4.32.4
Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver
appium-flutter-driver  >=0.0.26-1
Depends on vulnerable versions of appium-adb
Depends on vulnerable versions of appium-android-driver
Depends on vulnerable versions of appium-uiautomator2-driver
Depends on vulnerable versions of appium-xcuitest-driver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver
utf7  >=1.0.2
Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/utf7
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/utf7
node_modules/utf7
appium-adb  >=7.20.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of utf7
node_modules/appium-adb
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-adb
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/appium-adb
appium-android-driver  0.1.5 - 0.1.9 || >=4.26.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of appium-adb
node_modules/appium-android-driver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-android-driver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/appium-android-driver
appium-uiautomator2-driver  >=1.44.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of appium-adb
Depends on vulnerable versions of appium-android-driver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver
node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver
appium-chromedriver  >=5.5.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of appium-adb
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-chromedriver
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-uiautomator2-driver/node_modules/appium-chromedriver

xml2js  <0.5.0
Severity: moderate
xml2js is vulnerable to prototype pollution - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-776f-qx25-q3cc
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/xml2js
node_modules/parse-bmfont-xml/node_modules/xml2js
parse-bmfont-xml  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of xml2js
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/parse-bmfont-xml
node_modules/parse-bmfont-xml
load-bmfont  >=1.1.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of parse-bmfont-xml
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/load-bmfont
node_modules/load-bmfont
@jimp/core  <=0.17.1 || 0.17.3--canary.1136.7f5f5d8.0 || 0.18.0--canary.1133.54bf269.0 - 0.18.0--canary.1135.911ed04.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of load-bmfont
node_modules/@jimp/core
@jimp/custom  <=0.17.0--canary.1131.af3cb94.0 || 0.17.3--canary.1136.7f5f5d8.0 || 0.18.0--canary.1133.54bf269.0 - 0.18.0--canary.1135.911ed04.0
Depends on vulnerable versions of @jimp/core
node_modules/@jimp/custom
@jimp/plugin-print  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of load-bmfont
node_modules/@jimp/plugin-print
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/@jimp/plugin-print
@jimp/plugins  *
Depends on vulnerable versions of @jimp/plugin-print
node_modules/@jimp/plugins
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/@jimp/plugins

yaml  2.0.0-5 - 2.2.1
Severity: high
Uncaught Exception in yaml - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-f9xv-q969-pqx4
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/appium-flutter-driver/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/yaml
I tried to uninstall node.js, using another packages versions but I stucked here.
and of course I tried npm audit fix --force
please help ..